# Is there a limit to pages in storyboard mode in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Hello I'm new to developing apps for iOS Devices and I wanted to know if there was a limit to the amount of pages in stoaryboard mode

Answer (score 1):

Only by memory & disk space (on both the development and runtime machines).

Answer (score 0):

None that is documented. While that doesn't mean no, it does lend itself to a big probability that its either unlimited or an ungodly large number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a limit, both `storyboards` and `xibs` are actually just XML documents and interface builder is just a GUI for modifying them. Considering XML is a pretty light weight language, that can be executed without much effort by todays devices, I'd say it's a safe bet that you don't have to worry about file size. (Other than device storage limitations of course)

Comment: Oh cause im making an app that requires like thousands of pages so do you think it'll allow like 5,000

Comment: As long as you handle deallocations properly you shouldn't have a problem.